# How to find the most frequently repeated number from the command line, in an array?

Tags: java

I need to take single digit integers from the command line and put them into an array, and then find the most frequent integer. Sometimes this program seems to work, and other times, it doesn't.

```
public class MostFrequent {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int num=0;
    int[] freq= new int[9];//intialize array for integers 0-9
    for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
      try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        freq[num]++;//adds to array counter
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
    }
    int max=0,j;
    for (j=0; j<10; j++){
      while(freq[j]>max){
        max=freq[j];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + freq[j]);
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help, this is what ended up working for me, and thanks to whoever mentioned making the array more dynamic, that helped as well. **Here is the code I finished with:**

```
    public class MostFrequent {
public static void main(String[] args){
int num=0;
int[] freq= new int[args.length];//intialize array for integers 0-9
for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
  try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    freq[num]++;//adds to array counter
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
}
int max=0,j;
for (j=1; j<args.length; j++){
  while(freq[j]>freq[max]){//compares a max array val to the previous val
    max=j;
  }
}
System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + max);
```

}
}

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: I was getting array bound errors, and  I think it was printing the number of times a number was entered, rather than displaying which number that was. I believe I have it fixed now

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your second loop is flawed. Also, you haven't allocated room for all digits in your array, you need an `int[10]` for this. One way to solve it is like this:

```
int[] freq = new int[10];//intialize array for integers 0-9

...

int maxindex = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++){
    if (freq[j] > freq[maxIndex]) {
        maxIndex = j;
    }
}
System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + j + ", that appears " + freq[j] + " times.";
```

Comment: I changed your first line to allow any length

> int[] freq = new int[args.length];

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop

```
int max=freq[0];
int maxIndex = 0;
for (j=1; j<10; j++){
  if(freq[j]>max)
  {
    max=freq[j];
    maxIndex = j;
  }
}
```

Also, you have wrong output.

Instead of (that will give you last number)

```
System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + freq[j]);
```

Use (which prints max number and its number of occurence)

```
System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + maxIndex + " - " + max + "x");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation to find most frequent number.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns maximum repeating element in arr[0..n-1].
// The array elements are in range from 0 to k-1
int maxRepeating(int* arr, int n, int k)
{
// Iterate though input array, for every element
// arr[i], increment arr[arr[i]%k] by k
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    arr[arr[i]%k] += k;

// Find index of the maximum repeating element
int max = arr[0], result = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] > max)
    {
        max = arr[i];
        result = i;
    }
}

/* Uncomment this code to get the original array back
   for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
      arr[i] = arr[i]%k; */

// Return index of the maximum element
return result;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
int arr[] = {2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1, 7};
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int k = 8;

cout << "The maximum repeating number is " <<
     maxRepeating(arr, n, k) << endl;

return 0;
}
```